# Symfony - how to deal with credentials that contain spaces in security.yml?

Tags: symfony1, credentials, sfguard

Seems like a simple issue, but I can't find the proper reference.

I have a system that has some permissions that have spaces in them:

```
contract admin
```

I need to secure an action, so in security.yml i have:

```
action:
    is_secure:    on
    credentials:  contract admin
```

However, it doesn't work: the user with this permission will still be restricted.

I've tried putting the credentials in single and double quotes and square brackets,
but it always fails.  If i change the credential to one with no spaces, it works fine.

I might be able to rename the credential, but ultimately i'd like to know the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
action:
    is_secure:    on
    credentials:  "contract admin"
```

should work

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the comment where you said you tried quotes and brackets. It really should take it with the quotes and handle it as a string. Try debugging the sfBasicSecurityUser.class.php for where this could failing.

Answer (score 1):

```
action:
  credentials: [ "contract admin" ]
```

Try this. The credentials should be on brackets. For more information:

```
action1:
  credentials: [ this, andThis ] # AND

action2:
  credentials: [[ this, orThis ]] # OR
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use it like this:

```
//security.yml:

your_module:
  is_secure: true
  credentials: [your_credential_name]
```